# How to set style for a conditional panel in Shiny

Tags: html, r, user-interface, shiny

I have the following conditional panel:

```
conditionalPanel
(condition = 'input.show_p =="1"',
    fluidRow(
      box(width =12,
          actionLink(inputId = "p_name", label = "Path"),
          HTML("/"),
          conditionalPanel(condition = 'input.show_l == "1"',
            actionLink(inputId = "l_name", label = "Path"),
            HTML("/")
          )
      )
   )
)
```

As I have seen in the generated html, I found the inner most conditional panel is translated to a div with `display: block` as below:

```
<div data-display-if="input.show_l == &quot;1&quot;" data-ns-prefix="" style="display: block;">
    <a id="pl_name" href="#" class="action-button shiny-bound-input"> LM </a>
                        /
</div>
```

The question is *how can I change it to `display: inline` in R*? Or in the other words, *how can I set style for the conditional panel in R Shiny*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an `id` for the panel, and then modify it in `custom.css` referenced file:

```
# in shiny dashboard
tags$head(tags$link(rel = "stylesheet", type = "text/css", href = "custom.css"))

#...

conditionalPanel
(condition = 'input.show_p =="1"',
  fluidRow(
    box(width =12,
        actionLink(inputId = "p_name", label = "Path"),
        HTML("/"),
        conditionalPanel(condition = 'input.show_l == "1"', id="pl_panel"
          actionLink(inputId = "l_name", label = "Path"),
          HTML("/")
        )
    )
  )
)
```

And, as you knew, modify the referenced style file (`custom.css`):

```
#pl_panel
{
    display: inline-block
}
```

Comment: Well, no. This CSS rule will be ignored since the html-inline coming from the conditional is always stronger (css wise).

Comment: Okay, apparently jQuery `show` is so intelligent, that it calculates the `display` property value without manipulation and sets this instead of the normal `block`. So technically, I'm right and you rely on this jQuery feature.

Comment: This in mind, just adding `style="display: inline-block;"` in your `conditionalPanel` should also work. (No Ids, no css)

Comment: @K.Rohde As I can't find it in R Studio intellisense, so I thought it does not exist for `conditionalPanel`. Thanks to your reply.

Answer (score 3):

Style can be added to a conditional panel just as to most other elements, using the style argument with a valid css string.

Conditional Panels use the jQuery show and hide methods, which have the feature to set the display property to `none` for `hide` and `show` to `block` *or any value the element had before jQuery was manipulating it*. This last part means, we can just set the `display` to `inline-block` and it will be preserved like regular styling.

A short version would be like this:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
    actionButton("show_p", "Toggle"),
    "Some text to wrap the", 
    conditionalPanel(condition = 'input.show_p % 2', id="nice", style="display: inline-block;", "hidden"),
    "conditional panel."
)

server <- function(session, input, output) {}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're wanting to use a CSS class selector, you can add a class to the `conditionalPanel` using `conditionalPanel(…) %>% tagAppendAttributes(class = "inline")`, then add `.inline {display: inline-block;}` to your CSS.